# How to view a particluar list of contacts or only my contacts in Django application?

Tags: django

I was in the process of creating a Django app. Once I login with the username and password, I will be having two links:

1. Add Contact
2. My Contacts.

Okay!! And now when I click on My Contacts, I am getting the list of all users. But I want to view my contacts only, I mean the contacts associated with these particular user credentials.

Could someone please assist me on how to deal with this scenario??

Here is the code: **Even though I provide valid information, it displays it as invalid one!!**

addcontact view:

```
def addcon(request):
         if request.method == 'POST':
             form = ContactForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
                 name = request.POST.get('name')
             dob = request.POST.get('dob')
             mobile = request.POST.get('mobile')
             email = request.POST.get('email')
             a = contact(name=name, dob=dob, mobile=mobile, email=email)
             a.save()
             return render_to_response('success.html')
        else:
             return HttpResponse('Invalid Fields')
```

Contact form:

```
 from django import forms

 class ContactForm(forms.Form):

    name = forms.CharField()

    dob = forms.DateField()

    email = forms.EmailField()

    mobile = forms.IntegerField()
```

addcontact html file

```
  {% extends "base.html" %}

  {% block content %}

  {% if form.errors %}

  <p class="error">Sorry that's not a valid username or password</p>

  {% endif %}

   

  <h3 align="right"><a href="/logout/">logout</a></h3>

  <form action="/addcon/" method="POST">

     <table align="center" style="margin-top:150px" cellspacing="5px">

      <tr><th align="center" colspan="2"><h2>Add Contact</h2></th></tr><br>

      <tr><td>Name: </td><td><input type="TEXT" name="name"><i/td></tr>

      <tr><td>DOB: </td><td><input type="TEXT" name="dob"></td></tr>

      <tr><td>Mobile: </td><td><input type="TEXT" name="mobile"></td></tr>

      <tr><td>Email: </td><td><input type="TEXT" name="email"></td></tr>

    </table>

    <br>

      <div align="center">

        <input type="SUBMIT" value="Add Contact">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="RESET" value="Reset">

      </div>

  </form>

  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: what about the model? you also need to use indentation otherwise this is very difficult to read

Answer (score 1):

You should add another Field in Your **ContactForm** Model that is for which the current contact belongs to (the user which has logged in)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = forms.CharField()
    dob = forms.DateField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    mobile = forms.IntegerField()
```

and then filter it by User.id

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to filter your query results - see the [django docs on making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

Your models probably have a many-to-many relationship too, so i recommend you read the [django docs on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships)

Note - it would be easier to help you if you posted some code (particularly the model and view)